# UITouch methods in an object not working properly

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I have got a SKScene name “Scene” in which I instantiate 2 objects of my class “Button” subclass of SKNode.
In order to not multiply the number of lines of code in my SKScene, I wanted to implemente the touch methods directly in my class “Button”.
Here is the code :

Scene.h

```
#import <SpriteKit/SpriteKit.h>

@interface Scene : SKScene
@end
```

Scene.m

```
#import "Scene.h"
#import "Button.h"

@implementation Scene

- (id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size
{
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size])
    {
        Button *button01 = [Button node];
        [button01.number setString: @"1"];
        button01.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) - 50, 160);

        Button *button02 = [Button node];
        [button02.number setString: @"2"];
        button02.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) + 50, 160);

        [self addChild:button01];
        [self addChild:button02];
    }

    return self;
}

@end
```

Button.h

```
#import <SpriteKit/SpriteKit.h>

@interface Button : SKNode

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableString *number;

@end
```

Button.m

```
#import "Button.h"

SKShapeNode *button;

@implementation Button

- (id)init
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

        _number = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        [_number setString: @"0"];

        button = [SKShapeNode node];
        [button setPath:CGPathCreateWithRoundedRect(CGRectMake(-25, -25, 50, 50), 4, 4, nil)];
        button.fillColor = [SKColor clearColor];
        button.lineWidth = 1.0;
        button.strokeColor = [SKColor whiteColor];
        button.position = CGPointMake(0, 0);

            SKLabelNode *label = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"Arial"];
            label.text = _number;
            label.fontSize = 20;
            label.verticalAlignmentMode = SKLabelVerticalAlignmentModeCenter;
            label.position = CGPointMake(0, 0);
            label.fontColor = [SKColor whiteColor];

            [button addChild:label];

        [self addChild:button];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch * touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];

    if(CGRectContainsPoint(button.frame, location))
    {
        button.fillColor = [SKColor whiteColor];
    }
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    button.fillColor = [SKColor clearColor];
}

@end
```

The problem is when I touch inside the button01, it’s the button02 color’s which change. As if the action is only apply on the last instance of my class.
How can I fixe this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is the following variable has global scope in your Button class:

```
SKShapeNode *button;
```

Since it is shared among the instances of Button, it contains a reference to the SKShapeNode of the last Button that was instantiated. In this case, button 2. You can resolve this issue by defining *button* as an instance variable:

```
@implementation Button
{
    SKShapeNode *button;
}

...
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reasons your `Button` has `SKNode` as a superclass. `SKNode` doesn't have a `size` property, which you can change, so it takes the whole size of it's parent node. Consider it as a layer of the scene. So wherever you touch, the latest `SKScene`'s child (which is `button02` in your case) will receive the touch.

**Solution:** Define `Button` as a subclass of `SKShapeNode` directly.